# Azure CLI - az storage blob directory exists does not work

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I have a not empty directory in Azure Blob storage.
[image: My directory Blob in Azure console]

But Azure CLI says that it not exists.

```
az storage blob directory exists -c jenkinsworkspaces -d "uild-pr-new_ecom-lora-ng_PR-5593" --connection-string="XXX" -o json

This command is implicitly deprecated because command group 'storage blob directory' 
is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use 'az storage fs directory' 
instead.
{
  "exists": false
}
```

Don't understand why?

I precise that is the same with `az storage fs directory exists`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are getting `false` back is because your storage account is a `regular storage account` and does not have `hierarchical namespace` enabled i.e. your storage account is not a `Data Lake Gen2 account`.

In regular storage accounts, the folders are virtual. They are real folders in Data Lake Gen2 accounts. All the [`directory related commands`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/directory?view=azure-cli-latest) will only work with Data Lake Gen2 accounts. Documentation unfortunately does not mention it.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, I just had to enable "Hierarchical namespace", then it works!